# How can I change the title of a Safari shortcut or app on iOS?

Tags: ios, icon

I would like to be able to change the title of a shortcut (especially web shortcuts set as icons). Is this possible?

For example, I have a Safari shortcut for Facebook. As an icon, it's labeled "Facebook". Can I change that to "m.facebook" or something else?

If so, how?

Comment: Web shortcuts made from safari to homescreen ?

Comment: @JashJacob - yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names of apps cannot be changed on iOS unless you jailbreak and use some tweak. Although **shortcuts** made from *Safari* using "Add to homescreen" option can have custom titles. The title cannot be changed once it's been  added to the homescreen.

[image]